# Jenkins pipeline - Automatically Send email before the build starts and after the build without adding any line of code in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Currently we are using "send.notifyBuild('STATUS')" in our Jenkinsfile (Note - the method, notifyBuild is from our global lib). I'm wondering if Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline projects has the ability to send emails by default, before and after builds. Without even specifying a line of code in the JenkinsFile.

```
node{
    try{
     stage ('Checkout'){
     checkout scm
     send.notifyBuild('STARTED')
     }

     stage ('Build'){
        sh "source ./environment.sh;mvn clean deploy"
     }

     send.notifyBuild('SUCCESSFUL')

     }catch(err){
        send.notifyBuild('FAILED')
        throw err
    }   


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using a global lib, I suggest adding this to your library. Here's a nice way to format it:

```
node {
    withNotification {
        stage ('Checkout') {
            checkout scm
        }
        stage ('Build') {
            sh "source ./environment.sh;mvn clean deploy"
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your lib's `vars/withNotification.groovy` file:

```
def call(Closure body) {
    send.notifyBuild('STARTED')
    try {
        body()
        send.notifyBuild('SUCCESSFUL')
    } catch (err) {
        send.notifyBuild('FAILED')
        error "Build failed, caught exception: ${err}"
    }
}
```

I find this pattern very useful for low-boilerplate pipelines.

Comment: Yeah this looks nice. Just a couple of questions

`1 ) Is it a must, to have the "notifyingNode.groovy" under the "vars" directory??

2) Don't I have to specify "node{ //your code }" in the notifyingNode.groovy? Thanks`

Comment: They need to be in `vars/` to be used this way (directly in your Jenkinsfile, without need for importing or fiddling with closure bindings).

I forgot to add node, fixing the post!